# Append image using javascript attr src function

Tags: javascript

I want to get the image src from a div with id post and want to append it inside a div with id show-image

Also I want to wrap the javascript in a function so that I can implement it in webpage

so far i have created this

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("show-image");
var tubeimg = document.getElementById('post-img').getAttribute('src');
theDiv.innerHTML += "<img src=" +tubeimg+ " />";
```

for the Html coding

```
<div id='show-image'>
</div>
<div id='post'>
<div class='inner'>
<img id='post-img' src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Sg5t3utxRzc/UwgyzbLVAAI/AAAAAAAAFBo/vYQX0Cphx8U/s1600/indian-bride.jpg'/>
</div>
</div
```

> 

Right now I am using `document.getElementById("img id").getAttribute('src';` but I want this

```
var post = document.getElementById("post"),
var tubeimg = post.documentgetElementByTagName("img").getAttribute('src');
```

But tis is not working I don't know where I am getting wrongc an anyone please fix this please

I want pure javascript no jquery

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var tubeimg = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute('src');
```

It returns a `NodeList` which you've to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` gets a nodeList, you need the first element in that nodeList

```
var post = document.getElementById("post"),
var tubeimg = post.getElementByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute('src');
```

`querySelector` has better support than `getElementByTagName`, so it would be easier to just do

```
var tubeimg = document.querySelector('#post img').src;
```

Which would give you

```
var theDiv  = document.getElementById("show-image");
var tubeimg = document.querySelector('#post img').src
var image   = document.createElement('img');

image.src = tubeimg;

theDiv.appendChild(image);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7EHE/)

Comment: Can you help me further to wrap this java code inside function

Comment: @user3014202 - Help you with what exactly ?

Comment: @user3014202 - Feel free to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get fancy:

```
document.getElementById('show-image').appendChild(
  new Image()
).src = document.querySelector('#post img').src;
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('show-image').innerHTML = '<img src="' + document.querySelector('#post img').src + '" />';
```